# Stats Model contingency table nd array 2 x 2 x k , cannot reshape

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

Consider below list of 2x2 tables and CMH(Cochran–Mantel–Haenszel) test results. We are trying to determine if each specific centre was accociated with the sucess of the treatment [Data from Agresti, Categorical Data Analysis, second edition]

[image]

```
tables= [
[[11, 10], [25, 27]],
 [[16, 22], [4, 10]],
 [[14, 7], [5, 12]],
 [[2, 1], [14, 16]],
 [[6, 0], [11, 12]],
 [[1, 0], [10, 10]],
 [[1, 1], [4, 8]],
 [[4, 6], [2, 1]]]

cmh = sm.stats.contingency_tables.StratifiedTable(tables = tables)
print(cmh.test_null_odds())
pvalue ~ 0.012
statistic ~ 6.38
```

The tables parameters in [StratifiedTable](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.contingency_tables.StratifiedTable.html) can also take a numpy array shape 2 x 2 x k, where k is a slice return each of the contingency tables.
I've been unable to wrap my head around the array reshaping, this based on the above 8, 2, 2 shape the list of lists can more intuitively offer (at least for me).

Any toughts on how to re run this same test with a nd array?

UPDATE: I've tried to reshape my tables var in numpy as suggested in comment below to a nd array 2 x 2 x k , with a transpose. The below `TypeError` is rasied when running the same test with
`TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc true_divide`

*Note*: in R the following matrix would return the desired output

```
data = array (c(11, 10, 25, 27, 16, 22, 4, 10,
     14, 7, 5, 12, 2, 1, 14, 16,
      6, 0, 11, 12, 1, 0, 10, 10,
      1, 1, 4, 8, 4, 6, 2, 1), 
      c(2,2,8))
mantelhaen.test(data, correct=F)
```

Comment: `np.asarray(tables).T.shape`  `.T` transposes axes, first becomes last

Comment: @Josef thanks. I've tried the above and added an update. I get the above TypeError not sure what is wrong given that the 2x2 list of list of contingency tables outputs the correct results.

Comment: Just to add if crossed someone mind this i not homework at all. I'm following along a [course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/biostatistics-2?)  and trying to replicate R examples in python as a method to also learn scipy stats and stats model api's. Just intrigued on why i cannot replicate the results of a CT on a 2 x2 format versus a nd array 2 x 2 x k, shape.

Comment: Your example worked for me with the transpose, `.T`. It looks like you have a separate problem with the `dtype`. Use float: `tabels = np.asarray(tables).T.astype(float)`  This was recently fixed https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/7279

Comment: @Josef it was exactly that, thank you so much for taking the type to check this.

Answer (score 0):

Just referencing @Josef comment as the answer. I missed/ not accounted for a dtype convertion.

Your example worked for me with the transpose, .T. It looks like you have a separate problem with the dtype. Use float: `tables = np.asarray(tables).T.astype(float)` This was recently fixed github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/7279